# Color pandas DataFrame value if larger than 1.5*median(column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,-2,0,-1,17],
                  'B': [11,-23,1,-3,132],
                  'C': [121,2029,-243,17,-45]}
                )
```

I use a jupyter notebook and want to colour with `df.style` the values in each column only if they exceed a value X, where X=1.5*median(column). So, I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Preferably, I would like to have some gradient (`df.style.background_gradient`) to the colouring of the values, e.g. in column `A` the entry `17` to be darker than `1`, because 17 is further away from the median of the column. But the gradient is optional.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses pandas 1.4.2, the Styler can function differently depending on version.

The simple case is fairly straightforward. Create a function which accepts a Series as input and then use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally build styles:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, -2, 0, -1, 17],
    'B': [11, -23, 1, -3, 132],
    'C': [121, 2029, -243, 17, -45]
})


def simple_median_style(
        s: pd.Series, true_css: str, false_css: str = ''
) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.where(s > 1.5 * s.median(), true_css, false_css)


df.style.apply(simple_median_style, true_css='background-color: green')
```

[image: Simply styled table with green background for values above 1.5 * median]

Simple support for separate styles for values > 1.5 * median and less than by configuring the `true_color` and `false_color` values. Naturally, more functionality can be added depending on specific need.

---

The gradient piece is a bit more involved. We can use [`get_cmap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/cm_api.html?highlight=get_cmap#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.get_cmap) to get a [Colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html) from its name. Then we can create a [CenteredNorm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.CenteredNorm.html) to form a gradient around a specific value. In this case the median value (1.5 * median) for each column. Using these two together we can create a gradient over the entire column.

Here I've used a simple list comprehension to conditionally apply the gradient or some false style (`''` no styles).

```py
from typing import List

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, CenteredNorm, rgb2hex

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, -2, 0, -1, 17],
    'B': [11, -23, 1, -3, 132],
    'C': [121, 2029, -243, 17, -45]
})


def centered_gradient(
        s: pd.Series, cmap: Colormap, false_css: str = ''
) -> List[str]:
    # Find center point
    center = 1.5 * s.median()
    # Create normaliser centered on median
    norm = CenteredNorm(vcenter=center)
    # s = s.where(s > center, center)
    return [
        # Conditionally apply gradient to values above center only
        f'background-color: {rgb2hex(rgba)}' if row > center else false_css
        for row, rgba in zip(s, cmap(norm(s)))
    ]


df.style.apply(centered_gradient, cmap=get_cmap('Greens'))
```

[image: Styled table with gradient centered on median value, but styles conditionally applied]

*Note:* this approach considers all values when normalising so the gradient will be affected by all values in the column.

---

In case the more general case is needed, an unconditional gradient centered on the median could be built with (the rest is the same as the complete example above):

```
def centered_gradient(
        s: pd.Series, cmap: Colormap, false_css: str = ''
) -> List[str]:
    # Find center point
    center = 1.5 * s.median()
    # Create normaliser centered on median
    norm = CenteredNorm(vcenter=center)
    # Convert rgba value arrays to hex
    return [
        f'background-color: {rgb2hex(rgba)}' for rgba in cmap(norm(s))
    ]
```

[image: Styled table with gradient centered on median value]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst @HenryEcker solution is well explained and detailed, a very simple approach would be to directly tackle your problem with style chaining, something like:

```py
styler = df.style
for col in df.columns:
    mask = (df[col] > df[col].median() * 1.5)
    styler.background_gradient(subset=(mask, col), cmap="Blues", vmin=-100)
styler
```

[image]